# Option pane is not opening

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

I am trying to display an  option pane from a Java application, but it is not working.

Below is the code

```
package sampleapplication;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Brin");
        int sample = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The output number is "+sample);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sample");
    }
}
```

Comment: So... do you receive an error?

Comment: No. It is showing "Running" status in Netbeans

Comment: `Messagebox is not opening` - what is a message box? Your code doesn't use a message box anywhere. A Scanner waits until you enter data. Did you enter a value on the console and hit the Enter key?

Comment: Why mixing `Graphical User Interface` with `Character User Interface`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dinesh,

input.nextInt() - will wait for the user to enter integer value in the console. once you entered the value click enter. then your messagedialogue box will be displayed.

use this code for showing the user entered value in message box:
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.valueOf(sample));

keep learning..

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Be sure that when you type your input (which must be an integer) that you're actually in the console window. I'm running from Eclipse, and actually have to mouse click in the console window to activate the scanner input before typing my input. You might also need to minimize some windows or Alt-Tab to find the dialog box. Mine was hidden by Eclipse when it got created, but I found it by traversing my windows with Alt-Tab.

Comment: Yes. The message box is hidden. Thanks for the response.